# Instal pgRouting on PostgreSQL 9.3 + PostGIS 2.1

Tags: pgrouting

Just installed Postgres 9.3 + PostGIS 2.1 on Debian 7.

PostGIS works fine, but installation of pgRrouting fails in psql.

(no errors while installing sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-pgrouting)

But this SQL:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;
```

gives

```
ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so": /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/lib/libproj.so.0)
SQL state: 58P01
Context: compilation of PL/pgSQL function "pgr_startpoint" near line 1
```

I also tried the combination PostgreSQL 9.2 with PostGIS 2.0, same problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you get the pgRouting Debian package from? Is it in the official Debian repository?

Comment: I installed the pgrouting like this, 

first I added to /etc/apt/sources.list this line:
 
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main

and then:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-pgrouting

There where no errors.

I also tried the combination postgresql 9.2 with postgis 2.0, same problem.

Comment: I just found out that before I try to install pgRouting, PostGis functions work fine, but after the installation of pfRouting PostGis fails. SO somehow the installation of postgis (apt-get install postgresql-9.3-pgrouting) has inpact on the installation of PostGis.

Comment: I can only speak for the Ubuntu PPA for pgRouting, because I maintain it, and there is no problem. Unfortunately I have no knowledge about the Debian package and who manages it.

Comment: I installed unbuntu and tried to install pgrouting, but there seems to be an other problem with the packages. I added the ppa.launchpad.net to the sources.list, but then apt-get update fails with:  Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found any idea?

Comment: I tried it and also got this error. But it's a problem with UbuntuGIS PPA, not the pgRouting PPA.